How to prevent Gmail from altering image URLs in email HTML?
I'm working on an event management portal using Django, and I send a confirmation email upon user registration. The email includes a masthead image. However, when the email is received in Gmail, the URL for the image is being altered, causing rendering issues.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
def view_registration_form(request, event_id, event_name):
event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=event_id, name=event_name)
form_template = get_object_or_404(FormTemplate, event=event)

view_only = 'view' in request.path

if request.method == 'POST' and not view_only:
    response_data = {field.label: request.POST.get(f'field-{field.id}', '') for field in form_template.fields.all()}
    email = next((value for key, value in response_data.items() if '@' in value), None)
    # Save the form response
    print(email)
    FormResponse.objects.create(form=form_template, email=email, response_data=response_data)

    # Send confirmation email using the event's email configuration
    email_config = EmailNotification.objects.filter(event=event, email_type='confirmation').first()
    if email_config and email:
        ngrok_url = 'https://######.ngrok-free.app'  # Replace with your ngrok URL
        masthead_url = f"{ngrok_url}{email_config.masthead.url}"
        html_message = f"""
            <html>
                <head>
                    <style>
                        .email-masthead img {{
                            width: 100%;
                            height: auto;
                        }}
                        .email-footer {{
                            margin-top: 20px;
                            font-size: 0.9em;
                            color: #555;
                        }}
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div class="email-masthead">
                        <img src="{masthead_url}" alt="Email Masthead">
                    </div>
                    <div class="email-body">
                        {email_config.message}
                    </div>
                    <div class="email-footer">
                        {email_config.footer}
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
        """
        print(html_message)  
        send_mail(
            email_config.subject,
            email_config.message,
            'from@example.com',  
            [email],
            fail_silently=False,
            html_message=html_message
        )

    return JsonResponse({'status': 'success', 'message': 'Thank you for registering!'})

fields = [{
    'id': field.id,
    'label': field.label,
    'field_type': field.field_type,
    'required': field.required,
    'properties': field.properties,
    'options': field.properties.get('options', []) if field.field_type in ['select', 'choice'] else None,
} for field in form_template.fields.all()]

context = {
    'event': event,
    'form_template': form_template,
    'fields': fields,
    'view_only': view_only,
}
return render(request, 'main/view_registration_form.html', context)

When the email is received in Gmail, the image URL looks like this:
<img src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/meips/ADKq_NbcRVtKX8-MU89n76291vvMOgc0-_OZNXq11ShmRpXV8rhSgqmfS-RQbZyl9dYGE1JdpPAVi53QGZ3qs3xaq9e9g52ESafSbgZwFfb_k1TexoAJjgoXW-pXuoJ_H8QeiToEMQwviLadIC9n7_oPbJePcHTQPvTNS_RJl7xqBeeIcvkO9o5_3EU1-Lf0ttswGRuxMh9GzFd9w452ZfXOiWaDjQ=s0-d-e1-ft#https://########.ngrok-free.app/media/email_mastheads/fcac3fdb-af68-4dcb-9f1a-84d0b4ed86d5_2087ZhZ.jpeg" alt="Email Masthead">

Instead, I want the URL to look like this to ensure the image renders correctly:
<img src="https://##########.ngrok-free.app/media/email_mastheads/fcac3fdb-af68-4dcb-9f1a-84d0b4ed86d5_2087ZhZ.jpeg" alt="Email Masthead">

It appears that Gmail is altering the image URL for security reasons. How can I ensure that the image URL remains intact and the image renders correctly in Gmail? Are there any best practices for embedding images in HTML emails to avoid this issue?
Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

I think this is just gmail that downloads the image and renders that one. It is probably part of gmails efforts for secuirty, and thus to prevent the "hidden pixel" from making a request, and thus revealing that the email was read. So not something you can do much about. Google uses the same tricks in search results to know that someone clicked the email.

@willeM_VanOnsem Thanks for the answer. I guess the issue is because I was using ngrok because I am still in the development stage and apperantly it is not trusted by Gmail
